# Make UIImageView image slightly smaller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, setbounds

I would like to make my image in UIImageView slightly smaller than it originally set for me.

I had send the contentMode to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill but I still want to make it slightly smaller.

```
self.imgCamera.layer.cornerRadius = self.imgCamera.frame.size.width / 2;
self.imgCamera.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
self.imgCamera.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: Why don't you try updating the size of your imageView's frame?

Comment: tried to update the size of my frame but it's not working

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your outlet from storyboard is

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
```

Inside your coding use this to make the "padding" of your UIImageView, this should give you the result of the image size smaller than your frame.

```
imageView.bounds = CGRectInset(imageView.frame, 10.0f, 10.0f);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create utility method:

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    // In next line, pass 0.0 to use the current device's pixel scaling factor (and thus account for Retina resolution).
    // Pass 1.0 to force exact pixel size.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

and implement it:

```
UIImage *myIcon = [self imageWithImage:myImage scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(20, 20)]
```

Hope this could help.

Comment: this method will only make the picture blur instead of resize it

Comment: Not really. UIImage doesn't have a scale or absolute size, so unless you force-downsample in Core Graphics or draw algorithms, it'll always resize to the view.